# What does "intended date of enrollment" mean when registering for the GRE?

Tags: gre

I am trying to register for the GRE this fall and I'm confused by what is meant by "intended date of enrollment" here.

[image: Dropdown labeled "Indicate your intended date of enrollment in graduate school"]

Comment: Note - these questions are there so that the company running the GRE can sell your information to graduate schools who buy this information to advertise to potential students.  They aren't actually necessary for you to take the GRE.  I would advocate for people to answer randomly.

Comment: Could you clarify what you found confusing? Granted I'm a native speaker, but the meaning seems quite clear. What possible meanings are you torn between?

Comment: @Nobody Using a season like "fall 2024" works in the northern hemisphere. :)

Answer (score 1):

To summarize and make a formal answer:

The intended date of enrollment is a future date at which you hope to begin study. In giving a date, take account of the fact that applications take time to process and some places have fairly definite (published) application deadlines for future enrollment.

At the moment, August 2023, and in the US, an intended date of Sept 2024 would be reasonable, or any date thereafter. That assumes that you are ready to begin the application process soon.